# SQL Delete Erro #1064

Tags: mysql, select, sql-delete

I don't know why this my DELETE sql command got the error number #1064.
My delete sql:

```
delete from nit.grades g where 
(select id_dep from nit.offers as oo,nit.subjects as s where s.id=oo.id_subject and g.id_offer=oo.id)
!=(select id_dep from nit.students as stu where g.id_student=stu.id);
```

but this sql Select same where clause is working.

```
select * from nit.grades g where 
(select id_dep from nit.offers as oo,nit.subjects as s where s.id=oo.id_subject and g.id_offer=oo.id)
!=(select id_dep from nit.students as stu where g.id_student=stu.id);
```

thanks for any help.
the Error message:
[image]

Comment: You have made both queries same

Comment: The delete command worked on the same db but in the mysql workbench.

Comment: Pls post the full error message because it tells you where mysql encounters the syntax error. That will give us a hint.

Comment: Oh, did you get 1064 or 1065 error? The title says the former, the body the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax with the alias of the table you use for the delete statement is wrong.
Even more in the subqueries you use the target table and this is not allowed in MySql.
Instead you should use joins.
From your code this is what I understood that you want:

```
delete g 
from nit.grades g 
inner join nit.offers oo on g.id_offer = oo.id
inner join nit.subjects s on s.id = oo.id_subject
inner join nit.students st on g.id_student = st.id
where st.id_dep <> s.id_dep
```

In the `WHERE` clause I'm not sure if the columns `id_dep` are qualified correctly because they are not qualified also in your code.
If this is not what you want to do then use your `SELECT` query which does work (as you say) as a join to the table, provided there is a primary key like `id` in `nit.grades`:

```
delete g 
from nit.grades g 
inner join (
  <your select query here>
) t
on t.id = g.id
```

Comment: changed the oo to s: 'where st.id_dep <> s.id_dep'